# Is there a way to detect that a widget is making the layout overflow?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to handle gracefully the multiple sizes of phones and devices on which my app will be able to run.

On iPhone SE, the screen is not really wide, so I would like to hide some labels (leaving only the icons) when the layout overflows.

[image: Screenshot that shows the problem]

Here are the code used:

```
  Widget likeDislikeLine() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
      child: ButtonBar(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          OutlineButton.icon(
            textColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, size: 18.0),
            label: Text('J’aime'),
            onPressed: () {
              // Follow segment
            },
          ),
          OutlineButton.icon(
            textColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.not_interested, size: 18.0),
            label: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              String label = 'Je n’aime pas';
              TextPainter tp = TextPainter(
                text: TextSpan(text: label),
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              );
              tp.layout(maxWidth: double.infinity);
              print("${tp.width}, ${constraints.maxWidth}");

              return tp.width < constraints.maxWidth
                  ? Text(label)
                  : const SizedBox();
            }),
            onPressed: () {
              // Ignore segment
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

How can I detect that the current Row is "overflowing", so I could hide some label? I tried to use `LayoutBuilder` for that, without success: it always returns constraints with an `maxWidth` that equals to `double.Infinity`.

Comment: Have you tried using MediaQuery?

Comment: I could, but it would mean that I have to hardcode a breaking point, and I'd rather not if it is possible.

Comment: Not constructive at all, but owning an iphone SE since quite a while, it seems even apple gave up with the design on that device specifically: many applications have several overflows.. Even official ones. That said, did you check this already? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4128

Comment: You can use MediaQuery to get the width of the device and after that you could try to get say 90% (0.9) times of the total width. You can calculate other stuffs this way.

Comment: I would go with @CopsOnRoad's route. At least that is the way I am currently going on my application

Comment: Maybe instead of detecting size of widget you could use Wrap - maybe it helps you to solve this problem